# Can leaving rechargeable batteries in the unplugged charger for a few weeks cause batteries to lose their charge?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, discharge

Is it okay to leave rechargeable batteries in charger even if it's not plugged in?

Comment: "Indefinitely" is a long time - all things turn to dust

Comment: Oh it's "a few weeks now"

Comment: Yes. I'm a professional joke killer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the charger you won't know until you examine it, but generally I would say yes, it hurts your battery. It doesn't take too much current (a few mA) depending on battery, to cause permanent damage after a few months.

Comment: Assuming that we're all talking about Ni chemistry batteries (NiMH / NiCd) and single cell batteries (AAA, AA, etc.) by what means do you suggest that permanent damage would occur? Discharge through the charger when unplugged?  Definitely.  But damage?  I'd posit that damage would only happen with chargers that connect multiple cells in series such that there is a risk of reverse bias of an individual cell.